# Does N|Solid Runtime load balance websockets with sticky sessions?

Tags: node.js, nsolid

Load balancing web sockets seems to be a concern when using the cluster module(PM2 & Forever):
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/81
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075728/275491

Passenger claims to address this issue:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/nodejs/fundamental_concepts.html#vs-cluster-module

This link discusses "sticky load balancing" with websockets in relation to the cluster module:
http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

> Chances are that some of those clients might have an active bi-directional communication channel like WebSocket that we can write to immediately, but some of them might be using long-polling.
>
> If they’re using long polling, they might or might not have sent a request that we can write to. They could be “in between” those requests. In those situations, it means we have to buffer messages in the process. In order for the client to successfully claim those messages when he sends his request, the easiest way is for him to connect to be routed to that same process.

Does N|Solid also address this issue associated with the cluster module, of load balancing websockets with process affinity?

Answer (score 1):

The task of load balancing of websockets is better accomplished by `nginx` since you have more flexibility to store your sessions information (on redis could be) and scale very easy adding more process or more machines on demand.

In this aspect N|Solid behave same than Node.js

As you mentioned, "Sticky sessions" is a way to handle this. Storing and manging session information on Redis instance or other data store where your process can sync up, you can route correct session to correct process.

For performance reasons cluster module don't share memory between process, so, best way is using sticky sessions and let the balancer decide route using session info. Sticky sessions also enable a way of any process can get same information from session storage.

Comment: I updated my question to be more relevant to the issue at hand.  This page describes it well: http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/  Essentially nginx can route back to the correct ip:port, but will the cluser module or in this case N|Solid Runtime, route to the correct process instance?

Comment: The best way there is design the app to be multi instance, so multiple instances can get same info from session storage and behave same indifferent of the process.